# In Deep Deterministic Policy Gradient, are all weights of the policy network updated with the same or different value?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, policy-gradients, actor-critic-methods, ddpg

I'm trying to understand the DDPG algorithm shown at this [page](https://spinningup.openai.com/en/latest/algorithms/ddpg.html). I don't know what should the result of the gradient at step 14 be.

[image]

Is it a scalar that I have to use to update all the weights (so all weights are updated with the same value)? Or is it a list with a different values to use for updating for each weight? I'm used to working with loss functions and an $y$ target, but here I don't have them so I'm quite confused.

Answer (score 1):

Each Q output is a scalar, so the sum of all those is a scalar. Thus, you're taking a gradient wrt your parameters of a scalar. The result is a vector with one entry per parameter.

Comment: So to have those entries I have to compute the jacobian?

Comment: Yeah, basically.